# Join mysql nao filtrando corretamente

Tags: mysql

Salve, salve galerinha, estou tendo um problema que ta tirando meu sono kkkkk
seguinte, tenho 2 tabelas relacionais e preciso contar o numero de registros de uma delas, seguindo o critério.

**Tabela 1 - trabalhos**

id -
data -
escritorio -
trabalho

**Tabela 2 - participantes**

id -
trabalho -
participante

preciso saber quantos participantes teve em cada trabalho executado. tipo, o trabalho **X** teve 4 participantes no mes de julho/22.

Meu join...

```
SELECT p.id FROM participantes INNER JOIN participantes p, trabalhos t WHERE t.escritorio='5' AND MONTH(t.data) = MONTH('2022-07-1') AND YEAR(t.data) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) AND t.id = p.trabalho
```

O problema que a consulta tá trazendo um numero não real, era para trazer 2 mas vem 24.
Alguém poderia dar uma força ai, kkkkk desde já agradeço companheiros Dev´s!

Answer (score -3):

Descobrir o erro galera, kkkkk
caso alguem precise ta ai minha solução.

```
SELECT p.id FROM participantes p INNER JOIN trabalhos t ON t.id = p.trabalho WHERE t.escritorio='5' AND MONTH(t.data) = MONTH('2022-07-1') AND YEAR(t.data) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
```

Desde já agradeço irmão!